# Setting HTML Text Fields via Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, forms

I was wondering if there is a way to set the contents of an HTML element into a variable in Javascript.

I have a form that gets filled by information from a database. I want a user to be able to change the values in that form, click an update button, and have the values in the database update accordingly. My thought was to pull the values from the HTML items in the page and put them into a variable.

The form is created using PHP so the information can be fed into the form elements. I'm not sure if this is my issue or not...

In this function, I tried to create an empty array variable, set the first value of that array to the contents of an element from the document, then post that text in an alert window to see if it worked. So far, all I receive is nothing when I click on the button.

```
    echo "<button type='button' onClick='updateForm()'>Update Record</button>";
    echo "<button type='button' href='locator.php'>Cancel Changes</button>";
    echo "<hr></form>";

    mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function updateForm() {
        var form_arr = [];
        form_arr[0] = document.getElementById('id_cubenum');
        window.alert(form_arr[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('id_cubenum') will return only object.
You need to get values from object property.

So use it like this
document.getElementById('id_cubenum').value
```

- Thanks

Comment: That was beautiful. I'd give you +rep if I could, but unfortunately I am unable to due to my newness to this site. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Are you currently getting `null` in your alert?

To get the contents, your code should look like this...

```
    window.alert(form_arr[0].value);
```

Here's an **[example](http://jsbin.com/iKoCAjA/1/edit)**...

**OR**, if you are trying to set the value of a text box, you can use something like this:

```
    document.getElementById('id_cubenum').value = "ABCDE";
```

Here's an **[example](http://jsbin.com/UcORIgo/1/edit)** of that as well...

Comment: That did it. These things are decidedly hard to search for on the net/in Stack. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this:

```
var controlsValues = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < document.forms[index].elements.length; i++) {
    controlsValues.push(document.forms[index].elements[i].value);
}
```